# Organizing integers from low-high and using structures in C++

Tags: c++, file, struct, swap

**This is for Homework**

So for my project I am given a file and I have to separate parts of the file(Car year,make, model, price and availability) into a structure (which I have done). So for this function I have to organize the cars by prices low to high which I kind of have completed. I'll post my function down below and what outputs to the terminal I need to have.

---

Here's the function:

```
void sort(cars cars2[]){ //Sorts the cars by price 

int x, y, temp;
float price2[5];

for(x = 0; x < 5; x++){
    price2[x] = cars2[x].price; //sets up so the prices can be swapped later on
}

for(x = 1; x < 5; ++x){
    for(y = 0; y < (5-x); ++y)
        if(price2[y] > price2[y+1]){
            temp = price2[y];
            price2[y] = price2[y+1];
            price2[y+1] = temp; //organizes based on price of the car
    }
}

for(x = 0; x < 5; x++){
    cout << cars2[x].year <<  " " << cars2[x].make << " " << cars2[x].model << ", " << "$" << price2[x] << " per day, ";


if(cars2[x].ava == 1){
    cout << "Available: True" << endl;
    }
else {
    cout << "Available: False" << endl; //Same display as from function 2
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is the output of my program

> 2014 Toyota Tacoma, $45.25 per day, Available: False
>
> 2015 Ford Fusion, $71.27 per day, Available: True
>
> 2009 Dodge Neon, $90 per day, Available: False
>
> 2015 Ford F150, $112 per day, Available: True
>
> 2016 Subaru Outback, $115 per day, Available: True

---

Here is the output I need

> 2009 Dodge Neon, $45.25 per day, Available: False
>
> 2016 Subaru Outback, $71.27 per day, Available: True
>
> 2015 Ford Fusion, $90.89 per day, Available: True
>
> 2015 Ford F150, $112.83 per day, Available: True
>
> 2014 Toyota Tacoma, $115.12 per day, Available: False

---

So the price swap kind of works where it does organize each price from low to high but it cuts out some decimal numbers-> that's not really a big issue but how would i fix it to where nothing is cut out?

The main issue is how would I make it so the cars would also swap around along with the prices? I know that my cout is organized to where the terminal prints out whatever is in the file and the only reason the prices are changing as needed, is because I made a block of code that swaps around the prices. So how do I make it so each car along with all of it's information is organized from prices high to low?

If any further information is needed please let me know in the comments or if my whole program is needed, I'll edit my post.

Also the use of string functions is prohibited.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Rather use `std::vector<cars>` and `std::sort()`

Comment: _Also the use of string functions is prohibited_ YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: @TheDude: will the approach you suggested work? My understanding was he would need to sort the cars array or vector based on car.price and based on this value, swap the entire car struct itself. std::sort sounds great if u have a simple array of integers. but here how will sorting work on an array of structs (cars)?

Comment: @techieChamp Sure it will work. You can supply `std::sort()` with a lambda function that does the actual comparison based on whatever you need.

Comment: @TheDude: got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your temp variable is an integer, but you are swapping floats. Make temp a float.

How to make the prices swap with the cars? Simple, don't separate the prices from the cars in the first place. Get rid of the price2 array and just do the swaps on the cars array. This means you use just the price to decide which cars to swap, but when you swap you swap all the fields of the car, make, model, price etc.

Comment: @john Wouldn't the swaps being done on the cars array not work because I would be comparing an array with a float?

Comment: @chrisHG No, you compare the floats in the array with each other, like this  `if(cars2[y].price > cars2[y+1].price){`

Comment: @john would I also get rid of the for loop underneath my int/float declaration since it’d probably mess the program up?

Comment: chrisHG, you really don't need the price2 array so yes remove that loop. You still need temp but since you are swapping Cars not floats, temp becomes a Car variable. You end up with something like `Car temp; ... if(cars2[y].price > cars2[y+1].price) { temp = cars2[y]; cars2[y] = cars2[y+1]; cars2[y+1] = temp; }`

Comment: @john Thank You! I got my program to work through this answer-I'll edit your answer to where it has the solution so others can use this as reference in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In line 3, you declare `temp` to be an int. So when you cast `price2[y]` to it, C++ converts the price to an int. Try declaring `temp` as a float to keep the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using price[] as an integer (not float).  i.e. the value field is in pennies.

Advantages - no float conversion, no rounding errors

Simple impact -

change report code from

```
for(x = 0; x < 5; x++){
   cout << cars2[x].year <<  " " << cars2[x].make << " " 
     << cars2[x].model << ", " << "$" 
     << price2[x] << " per day, ";
}
```

to

```
for(x = 0; x < 5; x++){
   cout << cars2[x].year <<  " " << cars2[x].make << " " 
     << cars2[x].model << ", " << "$" 
     << (price2[x] / 100)  << "." 
     << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << ((price2[x] % 100)) 
     << " per day, ";
}
```

---

For readability and consistency, you should consider moving this 'reporting' code 'inside' of your class / struct named "cars". (Also, remove price2[])

i.e.

```
for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) { cars2[x].report() };
```

and add the report method into cars class

```
void cars::report() {
   cout << year <<  " " << make << " " << model << ", " << "$" 
     << (price / 100)   // dollars
     << "."             // decimal point
     << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') 
     << ((price % 100)) // cents
     << " per day, ";
}
```

---

> how would I make it so the cars would also swap around along with the
>   prices?

You used this for sorting the 'duplicate' array of float prices:

```
for(x = 1; x < 5; ++x){
   for(y = 0; y < (5-x); ++y)
       if(price2[y] > price2[y+1]){
          temp = price2[y];
          price2[y] = price2[y+1];
          price2[y+1] = temp; //organizes based on price of the car
   }
}
```

Now consider simply sorting the array of cars:

```
cars  temp;  // instead of int or float, swap the struct
for(x = 1; x < 5; ++x){
   for(y = 0; y < (5-x); ++y)
       if(cars2[y].price > cars2[y+1].price){
          temp = cars2[y].price;
          cars2[y].price = cars2[y+1].price;
          cars2[y+1].price = temp; //organizes based on price of the car
   }
}
```

Comment: You have marked this post as C++ ... you really should use std::vector (instead of arrays) and std::sort() (instead of your sort method).